# Make Scrapy send POST data from Javascript function

Tags: scrapy

I'm playing with Scrapy and playing with this [tutorial](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/07/07/scraping-the-steam-game-store-with-scrapy). Things look good but I noticed Steam changed their age check so there is no longer a form in DOM. So the suggested solution will not work:

```
form = response.css('#agegate_box form')

action = form.xpath('@action').extract_first()

name = form.xpath('input/@name').extract_first()

value = form.xpath('input/@value').extract_first()

formdata = {

        name: value,

        'ageDay': '1',

        'ageMonth': '1',

        'ageYear': '1955'

}

yield FormRequest(

        url=action,

        method='POST',

        formdata=formdata,

        callback=self.parse_product

    )
```

Checking an example [game](https://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/9200/#) that forces age check; I noticed the View Page button is no longer a form:

```
<a class="btnv6_blue_hoverfade btn_medium" href="#" onclick="ViewProductPage()"><span>View Page</span></a>
```

And the function being called will eventually call this one:

```
function CheckAgeGateSubmit( callbackFunc )
    {
                    if ( $J('#ageYear').val() == 2019 )
        {
            ShowAlertDialog( '', 'Please enter a valid date' );
            return false;
        }

        $J.post(
            'https://store.steampowered.com/agecheckset/' + "app" + '/9200/',
            {
                sessionid: g_sessionID,
                ageDay: $J('#ageDay').val(),
                ageMonth: $J('#ageMonth').val(),
                ageYear: $J('#ageYear').val()
            }
        ).done( function( response ) {
            switch ( response.success )
            {
                case 1:
                    callbackFunc();
                    break;
                case 24:
                    top.location.reload();
                    break;
                case 15:
                case 2:
                    ShowAlertDialog( 'Error', 'There was a problem verifying your age.  Please try again later.' );
                    break;
            }
        } );

}
```

So basically this is making a POST with some data...what would be the best way to do this in Scrapy, since this is not a form any longer? I'm just thinking on ignoring the code where the form is obtained and simply send the request with the FormRequest object...but is this the way to go? An alternative could also be setting cookies for age and pass it on every single request so possibly the age check is ignored altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you should look into cookies. The last time I crawled steam they had some cookie that you could just set to pass the age gate like `ageverified=1`. You can set cookies in your `Request` objects to replicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just set an appropriate cookie and you'll be let right through!

If you take a look at what your browser has when entering the page:

[image]

and replicate that in scrapy:

```
cookies = {
    'wants_mature_content':'1',
    'birthtime':'189302401',
    'lastagecheckage': '1-January-1976',
}
url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/9200/RAGE/'
Request(url, cookies)
```

`lastagecheckage` should probably be enough on it's own but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Hello @Granitosaurus yeah, that's what I was thinking, although, I'd like to know what would be a good approach when there's no form in a specifc page and we need to make a POST request to some other page, Scrapy wise. I assume Selenium could be an option, but just wondering. In any case, will test your approach, thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroVK You don't need Selenium and can replicate the age gate post request as it should be very simple; I could write up an answer for that but it seems a bit silly to replicate the request to get a cookie when you can just set the cookie manually and avoid unnecessary crawling :)

Comment: Agreed although for the sake of learning, still wondering how I can send a POST request when there's no form using vanilla Scrapy :)

Comment: Feel free to email (it's in my profile) with any cases you have - it's usually quite simple. You have to figure out what sort of body the server is expecting, set `Content-Type` header and make a request with `method` attribute like: `Request(method='POST', body='{"body":"hello"}', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})` <- would be an example of POSTing json data.