# Steam Scraper form issue using Scrapy (how to send data if there is no form)

Tags: python, scrapy

A while ago I made a scraper that and it was working just fine until some months ago. It seems that steam has changed the HTML on certain pages. Mainly the ones with the agecheck or mature content.

My question would be how can I send the data steam needs in order to get over the agecheck if there is no form anymore? I wanted to use selenium, but I want to also use scrapinghub and those don't seem to work since I get an error that there is no selenium module when I try to deploy my code.

Any clues about what to do?

Here is the code before the steam HTML change:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    # Circumvent age selection form.
    if '/agecheck/app' in response.url:
        form = response.css('#agegate_box form')
        action = form.xpath('@action').extract_first()
        name = form.xpath('input/@name').extract_first()
        value = form.xpath('input/@value').extract_first()

        formdata = {
            name: value,
            'ageDay': '1',
            'ageMonth': '1',
            'ageYear': '1995'
        }
        yield FormRequest(
            url=action,
            cookies={'lastagecheckage': '1-January-1995','birthtime': '788911201'},
            method='POST',
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.parse_product
        )
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to send any form requests to bypass steams age gate, you just need to set some cookies; see related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012236/make-scrapy-send-post-data-from-javascript-function/54023924#54023924

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and come back with the result when I can  ^^

Comment: It worked, thank you! Should I post a response and mark it as solved? Or will you post a response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Scrapy send POST data from Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012236/make-scrapy-send-post-data-from-javascript-function)

Comment: I've marked the post as duplicate for closing - that's probably the best solution here. Though don't take this as offense as your question is perfectly fine just that stackoverflow favors more centralised discussion - don't delete the question as it might help other people find an answer :)

Comment: Of course. No problem and thank you <3